# Faster bitwise modulus for Lucas-Lehmer primality test

Tags: python, optimization, bit-manipulation, primes, modulo

The [Lucas-Lehmer primality test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%E2%80%93Lehmer_primality_test) tests prime numbers to determine whether they are also [Mersenne primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime). One of the bottlenecks is the modulus operation in the calculation of `(s**2 − 2) % (2**p - 1)`.

Using bitwise operations can speed things up considerably (see the L-L link), the best I have so far being:

```
def mod(n,p):
    """ Returns the value of (s**2 - 2) % (2**p -1)"""
    Mp = (1<<p) - 1
    while n.bit_length() > p: # For Python < 2.7 use len(bin(n)) - 2 > p
        n = (n & Mp) + (n >> p)
    if n == Mp:
        return 0
    else:
        return n
```

A simple test case is where `p` has 5-9 digits and `s` has 10,000+ digits (or more; not important what they are). Solutions can be tested by `mod((s**2 - 2), p) == (s**2 - 2) % (2**p -1)`. Keep in mind that p - 2 iterations of this modulus operation are required in the L-L test, each with exponentially increasing `s`, hence the need for optimization.

Is there a way to speed this up further, using pure Python (Python 3 included)? Is there a better way?

Comment: Your compiler should do this optimisation automati… oh, never mind. :p (Yes, I’m being a troll; this was just too tempting ;-))

Comment: Someone had posted an interesting suggestion to change to `while n > Mp:`, which worked (although I can't understand why) and was faster.

Comment: You do not appear to be handling the special case where n = Mp which still fits in p bits but should be reduced to 1. Not sure if that matters - it will just get squared and reduced on the next iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best improvement I could find was removing `Mp = (1<<p) - 1` from the modulus function altogether, and pre-calculating it in the L-L function before starting the iterations of the L-L test. Using `while n > Mp:` instead of `while n.bit_length() > p:` also saved some time.

Answer (score 0):

In the case where n is much longer than 2^p, you can avoid some quadratic-time pain by doing something like this:

```
def mod1(n,p):
    while n.bit_length() > 3*p:
        k = n.bit_length() // p
        k1 = k>>1
        k1p = k1*p
        M = (1<<k1p)-1
        n = (n & M) + (n >> k1p)
    Mp = (1<<p)-1
    while n.bit_length() > p:
        n = (n&Mp) + (n>>p)
    if n==Mp: return 0
    return n
```

[EDITED because I screwed up the formatting before; thanks to Benjamin for pointing this out. Moral: don't copy-and-paste from an Idle window into SO. Sorry!]

(Note: the criterion for halving the length of n rather than taking p off it, and the exact choice of k1, are both a bit wrong, but it doesn't matter so I haven't bothered fixing them.)

If I take p=12345 and n=9**200000 (yes, I know p then isn't prime, but that doesn't matter here) then this is about 13 times faster.

**Unfortunately this will not help you**, because in the L-L test n is never bigger than about (2^p)^2. Sorry.

Comment: @Gareth McCaughan: There seems to be a formatting issue with the code? Ignoring lines 9-10, the `n` returned seems to be incorrect, that is `mod1(n,p) != n % (2**p - 1)`

Comment: Formatting fixed -- thanks! So far as I can see, my `mod1` returns the same values as your `mod`. Perhaps the test cases I'm trying are failing to provoke a bug; can you describe choices of n,p that make them disagree? (Or did you just not read my mind correctly about how to un-screw-up my broken formatting?)

Comment: OK, works fine. It was just my interpretation of your indenting that was wrong. I'm still checking whether this can be an improvement... but it doesn't look like it, as you pointed out.

Comment: In Lucas-Lehmer, you're repeatedly saying s = mod(s*s-2,p), so each value you pass in is the square of a value that's already been reduced mod p, so it's less than p^2, so it's not long enough for my code to be any better (even if you fix up the little suboptimalities I mentioned). This also means, I think, that you'll never actually do more than one iteration in your loop. Which gives me another idea, which I'll put in a separate answer.

Comment: Er, no, actually you can sometimes have to do two iterations. That's a nuisance.

Comment: My idea, for what it's worth, was that perhaps overhead like doing more comparisons than strictly necessary in those `while` loops, recomputing Mp, etc., might be a substantial fraction of the computation, in which case standard microoptimizations would have helped. I checked: that doesn't seem to be the case. So I shan't bother putting it in a separate answer after all :-).